# How to upload DICOM (dcm) files using wordpress wp_handle_upload?

Tags: uploads

I'm using `wp_handle_upload` to allow users upload `.dcm` files in the wordpress admin panel, and it does not working fine. I am also using wp_handle_upload to upload other file types ( `jpg` , `pdf` , `png` ) and it's working fine, but it does not work for files with `dcm` extension. My code is as follows

```
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['dicomfile'];
    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
    add_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');
    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
    remove_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');

    function my_upload_dir($upload) {

        $upload['subdir'] = '/test' . $upload['subdir'];

        $upload['path']   = $upload['basedir'] . $upload['subdir'];

        $upload['url']    = $upload['baseurl'] . $upload['subdir'];

        return $upload;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `jpg`, `pdf`, and `png` files, `dcm` files, by default, aren't allowed to be uploaded by WordPress. You can add them to the allowed list using the [`upload_mimes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upload_mimes/) filter:

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'wpse409071_allow_dcm_uploads' );
function wpse409071_allow_dcm_uploads( $mimes ) {
    $mimes['dcm'] = 'image/dicom';
    return $mimes;
}
```

(I found the MIME type here: https://www.file-extensions.org/dcm-file-extension. You might need to ensure this is the correct MIME type for a `dcm` file.)

Comment: Thanks. I added this in `function.php` and  it does not working and I can not upload any file types like `jpg`, `png` , ...

Comment: That's odd. It shouldn't remove any MIME types, just add the `.dcm` one.